# Understanding prefetch_related with my current example

Tags: django

Say that I have models like these:

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    datetime_alert = models.DateTimeField()
    alert_type = models.ForeignKey(Alert_Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dismissed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    datetime_dismissed = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    auid = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    objects = Get_Or_None_Manager()

class Entity(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Entity_To_Alert_Map(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    alert = models.ForeignKey(Alert, related_name='Entity_To_Alert_Map')
    relationship = models.ForeignKey(Entity_To_Alert_Relationship,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Entity_To_Alert_Relationship(models.Model):
    relationship_label = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
```

The idea is that an Alert can be associated with many entities via a mapping done with Entity_Associated_With_the_Alert. As I understand it, Alert.objects.prefetch_related('Entity_To_Alert_Map') will fetch me Alert objects paired with its association to multiple matches of Entity_To_Alert_Map (one Alert may have multiple entities mapping to it). But after running:

```
for alert in Alert.objects.prefetch_related('Entity_To_Alert_Map'):
    print alert.Entity_To_Alert_Map
```

I get this:

```
My_App.Entity_To_Alert_Map.None
```

Verifying with the database I can confirm that Entity_To_Alert_Map does indeed have valid entries. Could someone help me understand how prefetch works?

Just to clarify, this is what I'm trying to re-create:

```
for alert in Alert.objects.filter(dismissed=False).prefetch_related('Entity_To_Alert_Map'):
    alert_d = {}
    alert_d['datetime'] = str(alert.datetime_alert)
    alert_d['entities'] = []
    for related_entity in Entity_To_Alert_Map.objects.filter(alert=alert).select_related().all():
        entity = {}
        entity['type'] = related_entity.entity.entity_type.entity_type_label
        entity['label'] = related_entity.entity.label

        alert_d['entities'].append(entity)
    response_data['alerts'].append(alert_d)
```

But I'm pretty sure this is the wrong way of doing it.

Comment: `alert.Entity_To_Alert_Map` will be a manager object, so if you're trying to get its contents you need to use `alert.Entity_To_Alert_Map.all()`. (That has nothing to do with `prefetch_related`, by the way, it's just the usual way of working with a manger.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to recommend and give a rough example of implementing this using a through model on the M2M relation.

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    datetime_alert = models.DateTimeField()
    dismissed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    datetime_dismissed = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    auid = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    entities = models.ManyToManyField(to='Entity', through='AlertEntity')


class Entity(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class AlertEntityRelationship(models.Model):
    permission_label = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)


class AlertEntity(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    alert = models.ForeignKey(Alert)
    alertentityrelationship = models.ForeignKey(AlertEntityRelationship, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And for what you're trying to recreate I guess it's fairly close, but I don't think you are getting any improvement out of your prefetch_related call, here's a naive example:

```
for alert in Alert.objects.filter(dismissed=False):
    alert_d = {}
    alert_d['datetime'] = str(alert.datetime_alert)
    alert_d['entities'] = []
    for related_entity in alert.alertalertentity_set.filter().select_related('alert', 'entity'):
        entity = {}
        entity['type'] = related_entity.entity.entity_type.entity_type_label  # Don't know where you're getting entity_type from
        entity['label'] = related_entity.entity.label

        alert_d['entities'].append(entity)
    response_data['alerts'].append(alert_d)
```

Here is a much better solution using the [`django.db.models.Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) class to do it all one line, though it is a bit more complicated to understand.  I recommend reading the [`django.db.models.Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) and [`prefetch_related(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to understand how it works.

```
for alert in Alert.objects.filter(dismissed=False).prefetch_related(Prefetch(lookup='alertentity_set', queryset=AlertEntity.objects.filter().select_related('entity'), to_attr='prefetched_alertentity_list'):
    alert_d = {}
    alert_d['datetime'] = str(alert.datetime_alert)
    alert_d['entities'] = []
    for related_entity in alert.prefetched_alertentity_list:
        entity = {}
        entity['type'] = related_entity.entity.entity_type.entity_type_label  # Don't know where you're getting entity_type from
        entity['label'] = related_entity.entity.label

        alert_d['entities'].append(entity)
    response_data['alerts'].append(alert_d)
```

I think this last example is the most optimized version I can come up with.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example, quick question, where does 'alertentity_set' come from? Is it convention for it to be classname_set?

Comment: Ah so `alert.alertentity_set` is a reverse relationship created by the ForeignKey on the `AlertEntity` model.  So if you have `alertentity.alert` as a ForeignKey to `Alert` then Django will add an `alertentity_set` property on the `Alert` object to filter the related objects.  You can change the name of this property with the `related_name` argument because sometimes two relations will conflict.  Recommend reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/ to understand all the methods available for this feature.

Comment: Quick question with this, if how do I "add" an entity to the alert with the relationship field? I've seen m2m relationships by using only alert.entities.add(entity), but that's by using the default mapping table that django creates, so how would I do it in this case?

Comment: I have created the relationships manually but I don't know if this is the right way

Comment: Yes that's correct! When you use a through model on your relation you will create the relation yourself, i.e. `alertentity = AlertEntity(alert=alert, entity=entity, alertentityrelationship=alertentityrelationship)` I recommend reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships